# SAS PROC SQL: How to quickly search if a variable contain a full substring?

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I have a problem like this at work:

Column `Code` has the value like, 1000, 1200, A1000, B1200, AAA, BBB, etc. Currently it is separated by spaces, sometimes more than one due to poor data input. And I am trying to check if a record contain a code that I am interested in.

`Interested_Code`: 1000 or A1000 or 444 or 555 or A555 etc.

I know a simple solution [from this answer](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Enterprise-Guide/Using-CONTAINS-in-an-IF-statement/td-p/191521):

```
A.CODE LIKE CAT('% ', T3.Interested_Code, ' %')
```

I have appended a leading and trailing space to `A.CODE` to ensure a "full" exact match are returned. Because if I simply do

```
A.CODE LIKE CAT('%', T3.Interested_Code, '%') or
A.CODE CONTAINS T3.Interested_Code
```

I will get a false positive for code = `1000` at a row contained code = `A1000`, this matches part of the code, but not necessary a correct result.

My code works above, but it is doing too many test and really slow. Is there a faster or smarter way in PROC SQL? The main table is about 100k rows, and each row has around 10-20 codes. The interested code is about 8k values. Thanks.

Comment: 10-20 code variables (`code1` through `code20`), or 10-20 codes in a single column named `code` ?  Do the column values contain any other information beside 1 code value that may or may not contain an embedded space ?

Comment: @Richard 10-20 code in a single column named 'code' at my main table. Each code is separated by 1 or more spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `FINDW` or `INDEXW`, which find "words" (by default, things separated by spaces or similar).  That is probably better than your solution, in particular because you won't find

```
"1000 "
```

since it doesn't start with a space, the way you are doing it.

```
proc sql;
  create table final_codes as
  select codes.*
  from codes where exists (
    select 1 from interested_codes
    where findw(codes.code,trim(interested_codes.code)) > 0)
  ;
quit;
```

However, this is effectively a cartesian join, and *very* slow.  It has to join all possible combinations - 8000 times 100,000, or effectively 800 million temporary rows before it subsets down.  It's just not going to be all that fast no matter what you do.

Doing this in a data step would be more efficient, in particular as you can more easily stop once you find a match.  You can put the interested_codes table into a hash table or a temporary array, and then depending on your match frequency it may be faster to search each *code* in the interested_codes table, or the reverse, but either way stop when you find a match (instead of doing all possible combinations).

Answer (score 2):

Try to use regular expression:

```
data want;
   set have;
   where prxmatch('/^1000$/',strip(code));
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two main problems

1. The code data may contain a space between letter and digits
2. The search space is over several target codes

The features of a solution will be

1. normalize the code data
2. search for any of the target codes
    2a. flag a record as *matches any*
    2b. elucidates which *targets matched* (a binary variable for each target code, or a result row for each matched target)

You would have to benchmark your installation for a performance comparison between various approaches.

This sample code is a mockup for 2a. A macro builds out a SQL case to tag an 'any match' condition.  The resultant query is expensive as it requires a normalizing regex for each row, and all case conditions must fail for a row to be excluded from the result set.

```
data have;
  code = 'A    1000 1111 C333 555 A111 Z  999 B 222'; output;
  code = 'ZZZZZ 1121'; output;
  code = 'A    1000'; output;
  code = 'AB1000'; output;
run;

%macro withAnyOf (data=have, out=want, targets=);

  %local i qTarget N;
  %let N = %sysfunc(countw(&targets,%str( )));

%put NOTE: &=N;

  %do i = 1 %to &N;
    %local clause&i;

    %let qTarget = %sysfunc(quote(%qscan(&targets,&i,%str( ))));
    %let clause&i = when indexw (calculated codeCleaned, &qTarget) then 1;

    %put NOTE: &&clause&i;
  %end;

  proc sql;
    create table &out(drop=codeCleaned) as
    select 
      *
    , ' ' || prxchange('s/([A-Z]) +/$1/',-1,code) || ' ' as codeCleaned
    from &data
    where
      case
        %do i = 1 %to &N;
        &&clause&i
        %end;        
        else 0
      end
    ;
  quit;

%mend;

options mprint;

%withAnyOf (targets=1000 A1000 444 555 A555)
```